# How to prevent short and byte getting promoted to int when creating a cassandra table using the spark-cassandra-connector?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

we are using [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) code to create a cassandra table:

```
df.createCassandraTable(
        keyspace,
        table,
        partitionKeyColumns = partitionKeyColumns,
        clusteringKeyColumns = clusteringKeyColumns)
```

where `df` is a `org.apache.spark.DataFrame` but we find that the created table does not use same data types as the `DataFrame`. Specifically we have some columns in the dataframe which are of type `short` (aka `smallint`) and `byte` (aka `tinyint`) and they get promoted to `int` in the cassandra table. we do not want this behavior. how can we fix this?

EDIT: making some edits to document our investigations. the call stack when `createCassandraTable` is called seems to hit [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b22a8b59846195eb7382b9ea639abb05cdac095b/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/ColumnType.scala) code which would promote `byte` to `int` if the `com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion` is less than `V4`:

```
case ByteType => if (protocolVersion >= V4) TinyIntType else IntType
```

However we have verified in our logs that we are indeed using V4 of the protocol.

```
17/05/24 17:43:42 INFO com.myApp$: com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion = V4 
17/05/24 17:43:42 INFO com.myApp$: ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED = V4
```

Our cassandra cluster is

```
cqlsh> show version;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.11 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

and we use

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
```

in our dependencies.

[DataFrameFunctions.scala](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/72c4bc6703b71854746d35a8f8cc2108f48f6730/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/DataFrameFunctions.scala)
       [Schema.scala](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/75182a1b17c2a70229afc3a0b8daa78f5f10af1e/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/Schema.scala)
       [DataFrameColumnMapper.scala](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b22a8b59846195eb7382b9ea639abb05cdac095b/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/mapper/DataFrameColumnMapper.scala)
       [ColumnType.scala](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b22a8b59846195eb7382b9ea639abb05cdac095b/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/ColumnType.scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `2.0.0-M3` version of `spark-cassandra-connector_2.11` does not have [these](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/commit/f4f7585ec100e89393cc3a434efbda0ceb3d266f) changes. the solution was to upgrade to `2.0.2` like below:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and that fixed the problem